# android - listview with custom shape

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, shapes

I want to make a listview that has a custom shape background for every item in it.

This is exactly how I want it to look.

[image]

When a list item is selected, the color of it is a little bit darker, and it has an extra corner in the right.
What is the best way to achive something like this?
I've tried to make 2 images, and add both to my selector

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/clicked" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/clicked" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/normal" />

</selector>
```

And set the listview listselector to it..but is not showing as I expected, and also i'm sure is not the best way to do it...

What do you think is the best way to achive this?

Comment: where are the drawables and the layout xml?

Comment: You mean the images? In the drawable folder..the layout xml is in the layout folder, do you want me to add the code? I want to avoid this method because I don't think is a good one..

Comment: yeah, you will have to add all of em, so one can easily find what is wrong